Maximum size of a set of vectors such that no symplectic transformation of its span contains certain vectors
Consider a set $R=\{u_j\}$ of $k$ unique vectors $u_j\in\mathbb F_2^{2n}$. Use those $k$ vectors to form a subspace $U=\langle R \rangle$. The subspace can be transformed up to symplectic transformations $V$, i.e., $U'_V=VUV^T$.
Define vectors
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{a}=\left( \begin{matrix}
\mathbf{e}_{1} \\
\mathbf{a}_{Z}
\end{matrix} \right) ,\quad \mathbf{a}'=\left( \begin{matrix}
\mathbf{e}_{1} \\
\mathbf{a}_{Z}'
\end{matrix} \right) 
\end{align}
$$
that always has $a_1=1,a_2=0,\dots,a_n=0$ while the remaining $n$ elements are free choices, and vector
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{b}=\left( \begin{matrix}
\mathbf{e}_{2} \\
\mathbf{b}_{Z}
\end{matrix} \right) ,\quad \mathbf{b}'=\left( \begin{matrix}
\mathbf{e}_{2} \\
\mathbf{b}_{Z}'
\end{matrix} \right) 
\end{align}
$$
where $b_1=0,b_2=1,b_3=0,\dots,b_n=0$ and the remaining $n$ elements are free choices.
What is the maximum size of $k$ such that there does not exist any $U'_V$ for which there is some choice of $\mathbf a_Z,\mathbf a'_Z,\mathbf b_Z,\mathbf b'_Z$ such that $\mathbf a,\mathbf a',\mathbf b,\mathbf b'\in U'_V$?

Note: I think the maximum case occurs when the set contains the $2n+1$ anisotropic generators but I cannot prove there does not exist a larger set.

Do you allow a and a’ to be the same; also b and b’? If in the complex space, it is transpose or hermitian in the transformation?

@goldboy a,a' and b,b' should be different and the transformation should be real
